# TableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath before ViewDidLoad

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, viewdidload, didselectrowatindexpath

I want didSelectRowAtIndexPath to execute before ViewDidLoad.

How to do it?

in didSelectRowAtIndexPath :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + 1] objectForKey:@"gid"] forKey:@"lastGID"];
NSLog(@"lastGID (saved) = %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastGID"]);
```

in viewDidLoad :

```
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastGID"]);
```

Comment: How is that supposed to work? How can the user select a row before the view has even loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use viewDidAppear instead viewDidLoad.

Hope, it will be helpful

Answer (score 3):

If this is all happening within one view controller, you ***can't*** do it. The resources / UI of a view must be loaded (i.e. the table must be displayed and outlets connected, etc) before a row of a table can be selected.